# gdcmanon - Requested cryptoraphic library not configured

Tags: ubuntu-16.04, gdcm

I am using [gdcmanon](http://gdcm.sourceforge.net/html/gdcmanon.html) to anonimize dicom files like the following:

```
LD_LIBRARY_PATH=../lib ./gdcmanon --certificate CA_cert.cer -e ./dump ./dump/anon
```

But it gives the following error:

`Error: In /home/travis/build/malaterre/GDCM/Source/Common/gdcmCryptoFactory.cxx, line 61, function static gdcm::CryptoFactory* gdcm::CryptoFactory::GetFactoryInstance(gdcm::CryptoFactory::CryptoLib)
No crypto factory registered with id 1`

`Requested cryptoraphic library not configured.`

How can I solve this?

Comment: You have compiled the library yourself? You have set `GDCM_USE_SYSTEM_OPENSSL` to `NO`?

Comment: @Bartłomiej, I am using the binary release available in github. Now that you said about it, I tried with both GDCM_USE_SYSTEM_OPENSSL=NO and YES but same result.

Comment: If a compiled version fails too, than I guess that it is more likely a problem of openssl.

Comment: @Bartłomiej, After compiling, now it shows only "Requested cryptoraphic library not configured"

Comment: Do you have `libssl-dev` package installed? And if you compile, `GDCM_USE_SYSTEM_OPENSSL` should be `YES`.

Comment: @Bartłomiej, Few moments ago I found this link and installed them and now compiling again. https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/a/49429

Comment: @Bartłomiej, Alright! It worked! But does that mean it will have to be compiled on every PC that I will use the binaries on?

Comment: There should be no problem if you use binaries from the repository (`libgdcm-tools` on Ubuntu). The binary version you have obtained must have had dependencies unresolved.

Comment: I wish you said that before. Also that requires cmake version less than 3 I think

Comment: Well, that is the point of discussion - 12 hours ago I wasn't aware of everything that I do know right now. :-) Also, it is strange what you say about CMake. In my opinion, the newest version should be fine on Linux.

Comment: Not for the one you suggested (libgdcm-tools on Ubuntu). Not sure 100% though. But yeah, you've been of great help without any doubt. Feel free to give an answer, if you won't may be I will few days later. :D

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/166560/discussion-between-bartlomiej-and-nafis).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error is because of binaries you use, it looks like SSL dependencies are not satisfied.

As a solution (workaround?), you can get the binaries via `apt` system. For Ubuntu 16.04 Xenial distribution, there is  version 2.6.3 of `libgdcm-tools` package.

Another possibility is to compile gdcm from scratch, but you need development files of OpenSSL (`apt install libssl-dev`). Moreover, to use anonymisation with certificates, in CMake system set `GDCM_USE_SYSTEM_OPENSSL=YES`.